# pub.dev add user/contributor/uploader to package

Tags: flutter, dart, package, publish

I want to add a new user to my pub.dev package, who wants to contribute to my package, but I didn't find any way to do that?

This is my package: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web

Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to allow someone else to be able to publish the package to `pub.dev`?

Comment: Yes :) I want to allow others to upload release

Comment: Since that package has a verified publisher, I suspect that you can't allow someone else to publish that specific package without also allowing them to publish all of your other packages.

Comment: Can I revert that?

Comment: According to the note for https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing#transferring-a-package-to-a-verified-publisher, no, once a package has a verified publisher, it can only be transferred to another verified publisher.

Comment: Alright thanks for the link :)